# Are all D>2 fractals (not necessarily self-similar) non-orientable in R^3?

Tags: logic

In my mind, they are all non-orientable, yet I have no formal argument.
Here's my intuitive reasoning (might be 100% wrong but it's what I have so far):

1. Some demonstrations of non-orientability involve differential manifolds... which fractals are not.
2. Infinite detail means the impossibility of choosing a normal to the surface for an "up" or "down" direction.
3. More rigorous definitions related for example to the Betti number relies on integer dimension... which again cannot be the case except for certain cases (not our D>2 case).
4. Scale resolution dependency prevents any triangulation.
   And more...
   Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think you need to formulate a precise definition of "orientable" in this context.  A fractal might be totally disconnected, in which case it's hard for me to conceive of what "orientable" could possibly mean, as no continuous motion is possible.

Comment: The notion of orientations makes sense for manifolds or objects close to manifolds. However, no smoothness is required. In particular, there are orientable fractal surfaces in $R^3$.

Comment: Moishe Kohan, can you please give examples of such surfaces?

Comment: My question is actually related to strange attractors of some chaotic systems. I have a hunch that they are non-orientable in general